# How can I put a small image in the bottom left corner of a bigger image in CSS?

Tags: css

I just finished my captcha script so it has the captcha image then next to it I have a link that is a small image that can be clicked to refresh the image to a new one.

I am wanting to make this small image be on top, on the bottom left corner of the large image, can someone help me with the CSS?  Below is my complete code

```
<img src="captcha.php?sid=<?php echo md5(uniqid(time())); ?>" id="image" align="absmiddle" />
<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('image').src = 'captcha.php?sid=' + Math.random(); return false">
<img src="refresh.gif" alt="Reload a new image" border="0">
</a>
```

Comment: Also, I'd like to point out in your code there, the a element is entirely unessecary. You can put the onclick handler directly onto the img tag.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

HTML

```
<div id="images-container">
     <img src="image-big.png" alt="Big Image" id="big-image">
     <img src="image-small.png" alt="Small Image" id="small-image">
</div>
```

(if you are using XHTML, don't forget to change the end of the image tag to use `/>` instead of `>`

CSS

```
#images-container {
    position:relative;
}
#big-image {
    position:absolute; /* position:absolute aligns to the parent container
                          which in the HTML above is the <div> element */
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    z-index:0;
}
#small-image {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    z-index:1;
}
```

The important thing for the z-index is that `#small-image` has a higher number than `#big-image` . If your repeating this effect, use classes instead of ids.

Comment: hey thats great thanks! I have 1 small problem though, it aligns everything to the bottom left corner of my screen instead of just the small image to the bottom of big image, can you help me please  I tried removing=  bottom:0;left:0; from the big image and that fixed big image but now small image is on the bottom left of screen

Comment: Did you put them inside a div?

Comment: Because position:absolute aligns it to the parent container. If they're in a div, the parent is that div. If they're just in `<body>` tags, they're aligned to the edge of the screen.

Comment: @Macha don't you also want #images-container { position: relative; }  ?

Comment: @Macha: `images-container` needs to have `position: relative` for the whole thing to work.

Comment: Fixed now. I'm a bit rusty, haven't done much CSS in a while `*facepalm*`.

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to use the CSS **z-index** property to set which image will display on top of the other:
http://www.w3schools.com/Css/pr_pos_z-index.asp

You'll probably want to use relative or absolute positioning to position the small image:
http://www.w3schools.com/Css/css_positioning.asp

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need to do is to set css property position: relative; to #images-container div, and leave the other css rules as they were.
If you do that the images will be absolutely positioned but relative to their parent div instead of the body(whole screen).

Well.. good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Z-index stuff can get sloppy in my experience.  Why not just use an inline style to set your captcha as the background image of a div?  Something like so:

```
<div id="image" style="background: url(captcha.php?sid=<?php echo md5(uniqid(time())); ?>) no-repeat; width: 100px; height: 100px;" id="image" align="absmiddle" >
<img src="refresh.gif" alt="Reload a new image" border="0" onclick="document.getElementById('image').style.backgroundImage = 'captcha.php?sid=' + Math.random(); return false">
</div>
```